# Use Pandas(Python) to read really big csv files from Google Drive

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, google-drive-api

Good afternoon!
While using pandas to read csv data files > 500MB from my drive, instead of getting the csv file I receive the "can't scan large file for viruses" HTML page. I've tried a lot but can't find any workarounds. Can anyone tell me if it's possible to bypass that?

Sample file:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EQbD11iRnbXVJMZNTVExfrRP5WYIcAjk/view

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fMXX.png)

PS can someone also suggest a better (preferably free) service to upload multiple big csv files so that I can use pandas to get the data from it... i have >40gb of data to work with

Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't used it, but google has an API that might help https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: dropbox has a free 2 gig account https://www.dropbox.com/basic

Comment: @Brennan i'll look into it :)

Comment: @tdelaney i actually have about 40 gb of databases :/ i'll mention that in the question
<br>now that i think about it there's no free service that gives this much storage space for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it's working for me as of 14/10/2020 though it was taken off of the documentation: http://web.archive.org/web/20190621105530/https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads